# Transform columns on Talend using TMAP

Tags: mapping, talend, tmap, data-integration

So I have this table as an input:

[image]

The "numero" column is either of "Type" 7 or 2.
What I want as an output is this

[image]

My tmap does not seem to work correctly. Can anybody suggest me a way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: could you try using a trim() , example row1.Type.trim().equals("2") ? row1.Numero : row1.Numero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If row1.Type is an integer, the condition in the expression that defines your variables should use the == operator and not the .equals("") method. For Var.Portable, `row1.Type == 2 ? row1.Numero : null`